# how round 4 decimals MySQL?

Tags: mysql

how can i round this number 237.704918 to 237.71 in mysql? i try round but the result is 237.7, thks!

Comment: hi 3rd digit after decimal is 4 so no change at 2nd digit. If 3rd digit is >=5 then 2nd digit will 1

Comment: can you explain the "4 decimals" in the title?  what are the 4 decimals you are counting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROUND(number, 2)` rounds to the nearest value, and `.704918` is closer to `.70` than `.71`.

If you always want to round up to the next multiple of `.01`, multiply by 100, round up with `CEIL()`, and then divide by 100.

```
ROUND(CEIL(number * 100) / 100, 2)
```